# Why can't I go to other routes then homepage on deployed laravel project on server?

Tags: apache, laravel, deployment

i just deployed my laravel project to digital ocean. The mysql database is correctly migrated and seeded (checked in phpmyadmin). I can currently surf to the homepage. But when i start going to other pages like http://-ip-adress-/test  it gives me a 404 Not found errorpage. After going trough some forums i think it has something to do with my apache configuration and the modrewrite rule. So i will provide all the files i edited to try and fix this :

I did :

- a2enmod rewrite
- sudo chmod -R 755 bootstrap/cache
- sudo chown -R www-data: storage
- sudo chmod -R 755 storage

**.htacess file in public folder :**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /var/www/gloops/public/
   # change above to your site i.e.,  RewriteBase /whatever/public/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**apache2.conf file in /etc/apache2 :**

```
ServerName localhost

Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/gloops/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**000-default.conf in etc/apache2/sites-enabled :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/gloops/public
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have `rewrite` enabled? enable it by `a2enmod rewrite`. Also make sure your `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` are writable as instructed [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation)

Comment: I have done this 'Module rewrite already enabled'

Comment: Then try to make your `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` writable.

Comment: i've done this by doing  'sudo chmod -R 755 bootstrap/cache' and ' sudo chmod -R 755 storage' and 'sudo chown -R www-data: storage'

Comment: And still the same error

Comment: I had the same symptom in nginx - can I just double check if you are running apache (in which case the above seems correct plus check how you have configured mod_rewrite, if your .htaccess), or if you are running nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `AllowOverride` to `All` and make sure directory path is pointed to your app root not `/var/www/gloops/public` on your apache config:

```
<Directory /var/www/gloops>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then type following commands from your app root directory,

```
$ sudo chmod -R 0777 bootstrap/cache
$ sudo chmod -R 0777 storage
$ php artisan key:generate
$ php artisan cache:clear
$ php artisan optimize
```

I don't think that `0777` is good, you can try with `0775` but for me `0775` is not working.

Comment: I did all these commands and i still can't go to other routes than the homepage :(

Comment: now i get a 500 error instead of 404 : Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Did you restart your `apache` after make a changes ?

Comment: If it return 500 error code then there is must be an error on your app not apache, see the network tab on chrome developer console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113207/discussion-between-rifki-and-jim-peeters).